# Installing nvidia-418

Tags: nvidia

I'm trying to install cuda toolkit 9.1.

Descending into the dependencies one of them is nvidia-418.

Upon running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-418
```

I receive the following error.

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
nvidia-418
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/104 MB of archives.
After this operation, 437 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 279654 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-418_418.40.04-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-418 (418.40.04-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-418_418.40.04-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package libglx-mesa0:amd64 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-418_418.40.04-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Should I uninstall libGLX_indirect?

Answer (score 1):

running 
    sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9.2_all.deb

and

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-418_418.40.04-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

allowed me to work through this. Might be a packaging bug?